# How can I use stored procedures in SubSonic 3.0.3?

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic3

I have a problem in SubSonic 3.0.3. When I use SubSonic to generate code, I can use all the tables in the database, but I can't see any of the stored procedures which had been defined in database.

Please help.

P.S. : I am using MSSQL

Comment: Are you using Active Record, Simple Repository or Linq templates?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the StoredProcedures.tt file. Running the t4 should generate the code for you to use stored procedures.